# LNK2019 error when using XLCALL32.LIB on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, xll

I am using an old C++ library that makes use of an external XLCALL32.LIB library file. This external library hasn't been updated in many years.

The comment in the XLCALL.H header file says below:
/*
**  Microsoft Excel Developer's Toolkit
**  Version 5.0
*/

I am using VS 2019 for a Debug x64 build and my linker errors are below:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Excel4 referenced in function xxxxx
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Excel4v referenced in function xlAutoOpen

A Debug Win32 build was successful but I get below strange error when loading the XLL file in Excel.

**"Unable to initialize cable order data. Missing static data"**

I am using Microsoft Excel for Office 365 32-bit.

I couldn't find any help online for this error and so I am trying a x64 build but I am stuck with the linker errors mentioned above.

Can someone advise if I should be doing a 32-bit build and if Microsoft has a newer XLCALL32.lib that I should be using.

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: A standard mistake is changing the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting for the Debug configuration but forgetting to do so for the Release configuration.   You need at least the 2010 version of the SDK to get the 64-bit library.

Comment: "Unable to initialize cable order data. Missing static data" I suggest you search in the code files for this string, as it looks like it is peculiar to your project. Perhaps the addin is trying to find some data, possibly from a configuration file but that is missing. What is the addin supposed to do?

Comment: As @HansPassant says, if you can build the Debug version, but not the Release it is likely that your project settings for Release don't have the right Linker settings. Also, since you have a debug version that compiles, why not step through it in the Debugger. Put a breakpoint in xlAutoOpen, as that is (usually) what is being run as the addin is opened, and any initialization of static variables is done. Is the error in a message box, or an unhandled exception? It is also possible that the original author never built or tested a Release version: just got Debug working and left it at that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a 32-bit DLL or import library (LIB) in a 64-bit build. So, yes, you *must* do a 32-bit build if you plan to use this LIB. You will also need to do a 32-bit build anyway, since you're targeting a 32-bit version of Office.

Additionally, since this LIB was surely built with an older version of the compiler, it is not surprising that you would be seeing errors. LIB files do not maintain binary compatibility across compiler versions. (And *especially* not across major version releases of the compiler.)

I would recommend obtaining a newer version of this library. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/creating-xlls). It should be shipped with the Microsoft Office SDK. Download the correct SDK matching the version number of Office that you are targeting with your C++ code.